# Increment a variable with numeric and uppercase letter

Tags: php

Can you tell me how I can increment a variable in PHP from 00 to ZZ ?

With A5, 8R, GG...

I tried this but it's just for letter :

```
for($i="AA"; $i<="ZZ" AND strlen($i)<=2; $i++)
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you expect when you increment `A5`? And `99`?

Comment: A5 -> A6, A9 -> AA, 1Z -> 20, 99 -> 9A, 9Z -> A0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i created a little snippet that should demonstrate how you can use `range($start,$end)` to create what you are looking for

```
<?php 
//create an array with all values from 0-9 and A-Z
$range = array_merge(range("0","9"),range("A","Z"));

//create counter-aray
$counter = array();

//loop through the range
foreach($range as $value1){
    foreach($range as $value2){
        $counter[] = $value1.$value2;
    }
}

//show the counter
print_r($counter);
?>
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00
    [1] => 01
    [2] => 02
    [3] => 03
    [4] => 04
    [5] => 05
    [6] => 06
    [7] => 07
    [8] => 08
    [9] => 09
    [10] => 0A
    [11] => 0B
    [12] => 0C
    [13] => 0D
    [14] => 0E
    [15] => 0F
    [16] => 0G
    [17] => 0H
    [18] => 0I
    [19] => 0J
    [20] => 0K
    [21] => 0L
.....many more values follow here
)
```

feel free to ask questions if you need further explaination

Comment: Shoudn't `$counter[] = $value.$value2;` be `$counter[] = $value1.$value2;`? (notice the `1` before `.$value2`)

Comment: Perfect, thank you ! Just a little typing error, you forgot a 1 : $counter[] = $value1.$value2;

Answer (score 1):

It actually sounds as if you are trying to add numbers in *base 36*. Since PHP can convert between bases, [you could add the numbers in base 10 then convert into base 36.](https://ideone.com/ebrD49)

```
for($i = 0; $i <= base_convert("zz", 36, 10); $i++) {
    echo(str_pad(strtoupper(base_convert($i, 10, 36)), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL);    
}
```

- `$i` is an integer in base 10 that will loop from 0 to 1295. (`zz` in base 10.)
- `base_convert` converts `$i` from base 10 to base 36.
- `strtoupper` converts the resulting string to uppercase so you get `AA` instead of `aa`.
- `str_pad` will add leading `0`s to convert values such as `0` to `00`.